# CustomMaskWarning when using Keras OxfordPets code

Tags: python, keras, tf.keras

I'm on a project that is taking the Oxford Pets code https://keras.io/examples/vision/oxford_pets_image_segmentation/ and modifying it various ways. We're getting the following warning (when running on Google Colab), and it turns out that the original Oxford Pets code gets that too (also on Google Colab). Is there a way to change the code to not cause the warning?

Here is the warning we get when saving and training the model:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py:497: CustomMaskWarning: Custom mask layers require a config and must override get_config. When loading, the custom mask layer must be passed to the custom_objects argument.
category=CustomMaskWarning)

Comment: This warning appears when saving or training all ResNet models on tf 2.5 It isn't a problem from your code specifically. Other models might also show this warning like BERT on TF's own official tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/fine_tune_bert

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by @Henrique Mendonça, This warning appears when we use Resnet model on Tfv2.5.

These warnings will not hamper your code execution, still you can suppress these warnings using following code

```
import logging, os
logging.disable(logging.WARNING)
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "3"
import tensorflow as tf
```